# Search for rot13 text

Tags: search-engines

Is it possible to do web searches for ROT13 text?

I guess you could type in the literal ROT13'd text you're after, but that'd only cover exact matches.

**Background**: Became curious once I did a ROT13 tweet about a tv program being a mockumentary.

Comment: are you looking for a method to do this with Google, Bing, or some other existing service, or are you just looking for a treatise on the theoretical *is it possible* question?  this site is for questions that are fairly concrete, and so far i don't see it in this one.  the latter might be reasonable for Stack Overflow if you tag it *[algorithms]* though.

Comment: @quack: searching the web using an existing service.

Answer (score 4):

One way to get a decent idea whether the text is ROT13 encoded would be to search for common sequences/words.

For instance, if you were looking for ROT13 english text you could search for:

> gur bs gb naq n va vf vg lbh gung

which is the top ten english words according to [world-english.org](http://www.world-english.org/english500.htm):

> the of to and a in is it you that

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=&q=gur+bs+gb+naq+n+va+vf+vg+lbh+gung&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=&gs_rfai=

Answer (score 2):

[Rot-13](http://www.rot13.com/info.php) is a simple [substitution cipher](http://www.quadibloc.com/crypto/ppen01.htm) that can be readily [cryptanalyzed](http://www.cryptogram.org/), using paper-and-pencil techniques.

These techniques would allow you to look for common plaintext words (such as "the", "a", "is", etc. in English) encoded (or enciphered) using Rot-13.

Because of the simplicity of the substitution cipher it does not conceal [natural language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language#Defining_natural_language) characteristics, such as [letter frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency), so you could analyze a page or text looking at the letter frequency of the plaintext natural language (e.g. [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language), Dutch) as encoded by Rot-13.

For example 'e' is the most common letter in English writings, so you would expect 'r' to be the most common letter (on average) of Rot-13 English text. Followed by 'g' (plaintext: t), 'n' (a), and 'b' (o).

This would be simple to write a [WWW search spider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) to look for, but somewhat tedious to manually use existing online search engines (i.e. Google, [Cuil](http://www.cuil.com/), or [Yebol](http://www.yebol.com/)).

Comment: nice answer ....

Answer (score -1):

You can in your defined way. Rot13 have no special characters like base64, or other algorithms, which can define rot13 text.

Comment: I spoked about this `I guess you could type in the literal ROT13'd text you're after, but that'd only cover exact matches.`. He can do that! Or I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, he can. I thought you wrote "You can/cannot in _a_ defined way." Which when combined with your second sentence as evidence (lack of standard header) would make sense. Sorry for the confusion.